# PGError: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean ~~* unknown

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, heroku

Locally I’m developing with SQLite, but on my production host I’m running PostgreSQL. Locally everything’s fine but not so on the production host.

I have built kind of a search form with which I can evaluate all data in my database with any combination I’d like. This seems to work fine as long as I don’t use boolean and/or date fields. PostgreSQL doesn’t seem to like my code very much…

So, here’s some example code:

```
unless params[:analysis][:sporty].blank?
  tmp_conditions_customer << ["(sporty ILIKE ?)", "%#{params[:analysis][:sporty]}%"]
end
```

This evaluates to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE ((sporty ILIKE '%%')
```

Why’s that anyway? Why the '%%'?

For testing the deployment I’m using Heroku with the Exceptional plugin. This plugin gives me the following hint:

`HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Thanks Exceptional, but what the heck does that mean? :-D Type casts for SQL queries? How’s that gonna work?

In my migration the database field looks like this:

```
t.boolean :sporty
```

And in the form where I’m creating this data I’m using this code

```
<%= f.label :sporty %><br />
<%= f.select :sporty, options_for_select({ "Ja"  => true, "Nein" => false }), { :include_blank => '-----'}  %>
```

As I already mentioned, SQLite is my friend, seems to be the much stricter evaluation of PostgreSQL which causes the trouble.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direct answer is near the bottom . . .

> This evaluates to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE ((sporty ILIKE '%%')
```

> Why’s that anyway? Why the '%%'?

In SQL, the '%' is a wildcard. But your problem seems to be that you're building a WHERE clause that has two opening parens, but only one closing paren.

A WHERE clause like this will probably return (or count) all rows:

```
WHERE (sport ILIKE '%%')
```

> Type casts for SQL queries? How’s that
>   gonna work?

Standard SQL has a CAST() function. Skeleton syntax is

```
CAST (expression AS type)
```

So, for example, you can write

```
CAST (<any timestamp> AS DATE)
```

to change a timestamp into a date data type, or

```
CAST ('32' AS INTEGER)
```

to change the string '32' to the integer 32.

> In my migration the database field
>   looks like this:

```
t.boolean :sporty
```

If the column "sporty" is Boolean, this is your real problem. If you try to use a string comparison on a Boolean (which you did: WHERE ((sporty ILIKE '%%') ) you'll get the error message you saw. You want the statement to read more like these:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE sporty;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE sporty = true;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE NOT sporty;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "customers" WHERE sporty = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-). I modified my queries accordingly. But now I’m getting this error: PGError: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "". What now? :-/

Comment: @ulf: What's the new SQL statement?

Comment: The new statement looks like this: "sporty = ?" Leaving the " away results in an application crash.

Comment: WHERE sporty = true will work. I edited my answer above to include those alternatives.